# Key press opening unfocused tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I have the following code which works fine:

```
// click on the button
$(".btnHeaderSearch").click(function(event) 
{ 
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open('/search.aspx?phrase=' + $('.txtHeaderSearch').val());
});
```

It will open search.aspx in a new window/tab and the window/tab will have focus or will be infront of all other windows/tabs.

However, the following code not work:

```
// press enter key when textbox has focus to simulate button click:
$('.txtHeaderSearch').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) { // 13 is enter key
        window.open('/search.aspx?phrase=' + $('.txtHeaderSearch').val());
    }
});
```

What happens here is that the window/tab does open, but it opens a window behind all other windows, or it opens a tab without giving the tab focus, so I end up remaining on the original page.

How do I get the enter key press to open a window/tab which behaves the same way as the button click above? i.e. I want both bits of code to open a window or tab which has focus instantly just as the click even currently does.

I'm getting this behaviour in IE8.  It works fine in Google Chrome and I've not tried it on any other browser.  Unfortunately, I need to get this to work in IE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537632(v=vs.85).aspx:

> Ensure that all of the pop-up windows in your Web site open as the
>   direct result of a user action, such as clicking a page element, or
>   tabbing to a link and then pressing ENTER.

In fact your code didn't work for me at all, the IE default popup blocker just blocked it. I consider that unacceptable since most users would not allow it.

I worked around it by moving the focus to a hidden link (same as tabbing to it) when enter is pressed down (important as it's too late after keyup), and when it is released it will be the same as pressing enter while on that link so the popup opens.

HTML:

```
<input class="txtHeaderSearch">
<a id="hidden-link" href="#">needs to have content</a>
```

CSS:

```
#hidden-link {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    top: -9999px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.txtHeaderSearch').bind('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) { // which is normalized by jQuery
        $("#hidden-link").focus();
    }
});

$("#hidden-link").click(function() {
    var win = window.open('/search.aspx?phrase=' + $('.txtHeaderSearch').val());
    //win.focus(); 
    //The above is optional, if the window opens but doesn't focus then uncomment the above line
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/UCcqM/2/

This same workaround doesn't work for other browsers, so you need to detect IE and conditionally use the appropriate solution depending on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to click the button when someone hits enter inside the textbox:

```
// press enter key when textbox has focus to simulate button click:
$('.txtHeaderSearch').keyup(function(e) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) { // 13 is enter key
        $(".btnHeaderSearch").click();    
    }
});
```

Comment: Does that mean IE8 can't do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to cause a click on .btnHeaderSearch on the .txtHeaderSearch keyup event like this.

```
$('.txtHeaderSearch').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keycode === 13) {   
        $('.btnHeaderSearch').click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try adding prevent default first, as I have edited my answer above to show.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference either.

Comment: You might try to do something like this window.open('/search.aspx?phrase=' + $('.txtHeaderSearch').val()).focus() - added focus() at end, but results may be unreliable

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference at all for IE8.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in IE8

http://jsfiddle.net/74mtV/2/

when the first time it happens, it gives the popup warning, and no window is opened, but after allowing it both events open a new popup window with the focus set to it.

Tested both with normal mode and with compatibility enabled.

Comment: I got the same results as you in the first test, i.e. a warning message about a popup which I agreed to allow.  After that, it opens a new tab, but unfocused.  Why is it opening a focused tab for you, but not for me?

Comment: I'm testing in MSIE 8 but the version is written as : Version 8.0.6001.18702 Is yours the same?

Comment: some addons can interfere, can you disable all your addons or disable them one by one from Tools – Manage addons? And see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: ok what about "The option to open a tab in the background or switch to it immediately is here:  Tools > Internet Options > General tab > Tabs Settings button.  "Always switch to new tab when opened"

Answer (score 0):

Eg:

```
    <form action="page2" method="get" onsubmit="return func()">
      <input type="text" name="search"/>
    </form>
```

On writing something in the text box and pressing enter func() will be called, which when returns true, the form will be submitted (http://example.com?search=....)

So, for your problem you can just replace the values in the example and define a function to handle the pre-submission job.

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is in dynamic binding, the below links works for me,
  http://jsfiddle.net/madhuvana/McaXj/2/